# Doxygen: How to properly document a C struct member variable with 80-char limit?

Tags: c, doxygen

Is there a proper/recommended way to add a short Doxygen comment to a `C struct` member variable when you're trying to obey an 80-char width-limit?

E.g.

```
// MyStruct.h

#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

typedef struct MyStruct
{
  struct in
  {
    int i_;                             ///< A number
    MQTTAsync_connectionLost connLost_; ///< Callback invoked upon loss of
                                        ///< connection
    char c_;                            ///< A letter
  } in_;
} MyStruct;

#endif
```

The above doesn't seem the right way to document `connLost_` while obeying an 80-char width limit: it ends up generating the description of `connLost` under a "Field Documentation" subsection instead of along-with its peer member variables.

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

typedef struct MyStruct
{
  struct in
  {
    int i_;                             ///< A number
    MQTTAsync_connectionLost connLost_; ///< Callback invoked upon loss of \
                                             connection
    char c_;                            ///< A letter
  } in_;
} MyStruct;

#endif
```

That is wrong differently: although `connLost_` is documented along with its peers, the word "connection" (everything after the backslash) is dropped from the documentation.

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

typedef struct MyStruct
{
  struct in
  {
    int i_;                             ///< A number
    /** Callback invoked upon loss of connection */
    MQTTAsync_connectionLost connLost_;
    char c_;                            ///< A letter
  } in_;
} MyStruct;

#endif
```

That isn't what I want either: `connLost_`'s documentation goes back to being in the "Field Documentation" section instead of along with its peers.

Pictorially, what I'd like to achieve, in a "doxygen-native" manner:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered putting a line break between `MQTTAsync_connectionLost` and `connLost_`?

Comment: @Draconis - I did, and I'm not opposed to that (but it's not my preferred solution), but I'd like to learn if there's a "doxygen-native" solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did in the second example is ok. You just have to include a `\brief`!

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

typedef struct MyStruct
{
  struct in
  {
    int i_;                             ///< A number
    // NOTE THE BRIEF HERE
    /** \brief Callback invoked upon loss of connection */
    MQTTAsync_connectionLost connLost_;
    char c_;                            ///< A letter
  } in_;
} MyStruct;
#endif
```